# May I say "*A read* of the book leads me to enjoy..."?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I wish to convey something like 'when I read the book I was lead to enjoy the beauty of nature.....'

> Is it correct to say "a read of the book '...(book name)' leads me to enjoy the beauty of nature..."?

Comment: No. Native speakers might occasionally say things like *I'm going **to have a read** of my book*, but it would normally be both *intended* and *understood* to be a slightly quirky usage. The standard form for my example is *I'm going **to read** my book*, and in OP's case it would be ***Reading** this book leads me to [blah blah]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Check my answer's citation; it does seem to be in use.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: I wouldn't attach to much significance to that one. It's just an article title, not necessarily bound by things like punctuation and standard idiomatic usage. Don't forget that *as a title* it may well be deliberately "quirky" in order to catch the reader's attention.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: When a publishing company titles an entire blog series that way, I feel it perhaps means just a bit more than J. Random Typist putting up cat pictures with that headline.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: I don't really know where you're coming from on this one. I think the usage isn't something learners ought to bother with at all, because it's not at all common, and for the most part it sounds "quirky". You start your answer by agreeing "it's a bit odd", but now you seem to be *defending* it. If you were a learner, wouldn't you find these comments a bit confusing? FWIW, I don't recognise the "subtle distinction" in your answer at all, except insofar as whenever something is deliberately expressed in a "non-standard" way, we tend to assume there may be a context-specific reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I disagree that it's **wrong**; I do agree that it's **odd** and probably not to be recommended in most circumstances. There's no point giving the false impression that using it is outright incorrect, though, when it obviously can be and is used in professional contexts.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: Okay, let's leave it at that then. You think learners want to know about usages that I consider unusual, non-standard, quirky, rare, or whatever (basically, anything that might *feasibly* be used by a native speaker, provided it's not actually "wrong" in some definitive fashion). I think it's best to stick to telling learners about the forms people *actually* use, the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although it's a bit odd. [Example in use from a major publisher](http://www.tor.com/series/a-read-of-the-dark-tower/).

Usually it's best to avoid the construction unless you specifically want to call a certain amount of extra attention to something that happens *every individual read-through*, as opposed to merely when reading. If that seems like a subtle distinction to make, it is.

Comment: Could I say "upon reading the book 'name of book ', I was fascinated by the ....."?

Comment: @Rescy_: Yes, that would be common enough.